# Recyclerview stay at position after item click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

Heres my problem...
I have created an `RecyclerView` and implement an `OnItemClick` listener.
Everything works, but my `RecylerView` scrolls every time up to the beginning when i click an item. **Is there a way to fix the scroll-position?**

My listener:

```
mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(list, new OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String str) {
            // handle click works...
        }
    });
```

OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener is an Interface i created to handle click...

Comment: Share you click listener code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sry i found the error, in my listener i call an method, which updates the fragment in which my RecyclerView is implemented...

Thank you, for your fast answers!!
The question is answered...